# Spring batch tables

Tags: spring-batch

In Spring batch (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) there are six tables:

- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
- BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT

Are there no more tables for things like Job Registry, Job Repository, Job Explorer etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job Resgistry, Job Explorer, Job Repository are interfaces you can use in querying the Spring Batch tables not actual tables.
See
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/3.0.x/reference/html/configureJob.html 
look at section 4.6.1 Querying the Repository